# Load Selenium test cases saved as PHP files

Tags: php, selenium

I want/need to save my Selenium test cases as PHP files rather than HTML. I found nice plugins for exporting PHP test cases and suites to PHP, but I find no way to open the saved files with Selenium IDE.

Is there a way to do this, and if so, how?

[The background of the question is that I will make test cases that I suspect that people will put sensitive information in (db and other login credentials), and then put on a live server. With tests stored as PHP files, this information would be rather safe even on a web host. With tests stored as HTML, the information would not be safe.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium IDE lets you **save** and **load** test suites in HTML. Selenium IDE also lets you **export** test suites to other Selenium bindings (PHP, Ruby, C#, etc.). The exported files are intended to be executed from within those bindings, they are *not* intended to be imported back to Selenium IDE.

Given the background, you are better off saving the test suites as HTML and managing the file permissions on the server so they are not visible externally.

The alternative is to export the suites to PHP and run them from PHP. However in this case you have to make sure the exported cases are correct (usually not the case) and then you have to manage running these yourself in PHP (since you can't use the IDE anymore).